# Shipping checkout returns to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart, shipping, ce-1.9.2.0

I'm testing my shop: after the guest checkout, after the shipping method (step 4), the checkout goes to checkout/cart/ again. Anyone has an idea how to fix it? Vers. Magento 1.9.2.0 theme RWD

Comment: php version 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when an AJAX request during checkout returns a malformed response, often due to PHP errors. Inspect the response in your browser console, it probably either contains an error message that should help you, or is empty. If it is empty, turn on developer mode and display_errors in index.php and/or check the PHP error log on your web server as well as var/log/system.log of Magento

Comment: POST http://www.stampa-online.net/shop/index.php/checkout/onepage/saveShippingMethod/ 499 (Request has been forbidden by antivirus) cool, it's the firewall! Thanks, I never expected this